# Conditional sum after group by where I have to match condition on previous rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hello I have following table

```
id       | start_date | end_date   | state
52183371 | 2015-03-31 | 2015-03-31 | working
52183371 | 2015-04-01 | 2015-04-31 | working
52183371 | 2015-04-02 | 2015-04-28 | working
52183371 | 2015-04-21 | 2015-04-30 | not_working
```

In this table, I want to count number of working state where start date current row is larger than end_date of all privous row

Result I want to see is as follows:

```
id       | start_date | end_date   | state      | working_count
52183371 | 2015-03-31 | 2015-03-31 | working    | NaN
52183371 | 2015-04-01 | 2015-04-31 | working    | 1
52183371 | 2015-04-02 | 2015-04-28 | working    | 1
52183371 | 2015-04-21 | 2015-04-30 | not_working| 1
```

In last rows, since start_date is lower than previous end_date so I don't want to count it.

Currently I am thinking about using loop where I have using start_date and then loop through those unique start date and then use those start date to filter data and then do calculation. However, is there pandas way to do this one ?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? `(df.start_date > df.end_date.shift()).cumsum()
`

Comment: I can have multiple rows where that condition is not met

Comment: So, is that a good thing?

Comment: df.start_date > df.end_date.shift()).cumsum(), will able to match only on past rows, I want remove all rows where current start_date is lower than all past end_date

Comment: Can you provide a bigger [MCVE]?

Comment: I have expanded example to show you minimum, complete example, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your problem, you want to check the end_date of all the previous rows. I think one way is to get the `max` on the column end_date up to the current row using `cummax`. So if you do:

```
(df.start_date > df.end_date.cummax().shift()).cumsum()
```

you compare with the start_date with the max of end_date up to the previous row, which get your expected output.